# Please assist in creating a drop down list for months- Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I was wondering if someone could help me create a drop-down list in a single cell on google sheets that only displays the months names but also keeps their values

Until now I’ve been able to create the list but when I go to select the month it changes into day-month-year form

Thank you,
Gabe

Comment: Do you have a testing sheet and an expected output sample that you can show over your question?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOm-PIHAKTe-mYY20MHdJLXW1UqEvReao8za_UbuADk/edit

Pretty much when I change the month on the summary sheet I want the transactions sheet to update

Comment: In addition, I want other data such as the starting balance and planned values to alternate with the months

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2):

The way i understood your question, the easiest way to do it would be to just use data validaion: Select cell you want and in toolbar menu go `Data`>`Data Validation`>`List of items` and just paste this `January,February,March,April,May,june,July,August,September,October,November,December`

Then format cell as plain text: Select cell you want and in toolbar menu go `Format`>`Number`>`Plain Text`

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: I’m trying to use the month function with query so from what I’ve tried this doesn’t work

Comment: Here is the link to copy of your example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZjvNsGwKZcCI1mA9enqg5h_kB2F4khkzJi9dgbxofp0/edit?usp=sharing

I used named ranges alot, BB sheet is just transfer sheet for drop-down menus(also added that if you select income or expense in form it will change category drop down menu.

I hope this does what you needed.

Comment: You can always hid that part of transactons sheet after black columnor move that in bb and hide complete sheet :)